# python : cannot import tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow

I successfully created my tensorflow environment with Anaconda3 on my machine with the steps introduced on this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows). But when I try to try to do :

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
```

I get the following error messages : OSError and ImportError.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Froilan\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-
packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 75, in preload_check
ctypes.WinDLL(build_info.cudart_dll_name)
  File "C:\Users\Froilan\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] This specified module could not be found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Froilan\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
  File "C:\Users\Froilan\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Users\Froilan\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 30, in <module>
self_check.preload_check()
  File "C:\Users\Froilan\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\self_check.py", line 82, in preload_check
% (build_info.cudart_dll_name, build_info.cuda_version_number))
ImportError: Could not find 'cudart64_80.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable. Download and install CUDA 8.0 from this URL: https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit
```

Could it be something to do with my cpu? I use Ryzen 1700.
+ GPU : GTX 1050 Ti  - A bit inferior to 1080 ti or so.. but I've heard that GPU's would still be way better than CPU's.

Comment: Do you want to use CPU or GPU?

Comment: Could please also indicate which GPU are you using.

Comment: I want to use the GPU version -- mine is GTX 1050 ti

Comment: good, check my answer, apparently, you did not install or set the CUDA lib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to install CUDA library first, I would recommend to follow this link:

https://gist.github.com/mjdietzx/0ff77af5ae60622ce6ed8c4d9b419f45

UPDATE:
for the Windows OS, please follow this approach:

http://blog.nitishmutha.com/tensorflow/2017/01/22/TensorFlow-with-gpu-for-windows.html

Comment: Erp.. I think that's for Linux..? I'm on Windows 10. Or is there a way to implement that? Sorry I'm new to OS, bash and stuffs.. :(

Comment: Okay, thank you so much. But one more question which is somewhat irrelevant.. During the CUDA 8.0 installation process, my machine failed to recognize my second monitor. Is this normal?

Comment: I'm afraid google's not helping me this time.. Anyways, I'll try to find out what's wrong. Thanks a ton

Comment: OK, solved it.
FOR THOSE WHO MIGHT BE SUFFERING FROM SIMILAR PROBLEMS:
check your GPU driver. Update it, reboot your machine.