# I can't import tensorflow-gpu

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I've successfully installed tensorflow with `pip install tensorflow` and that all works as expected.

I can also successfully install tensorflow-gpu  with `pip install tensorflow-gpu` but I can't import it in my python script:

```
import tensorflow-gpu

File "<stdin>", line 1
import tensorflow-gpu
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

i've installed CUDA v9.0 and run windows 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060769/python-cannot-import-tensorflow-gpu

Comment: You do not need to import tensorflow-gpu , if you installed it, `cuda` and `cudnn` properly, you will be able to acces the gpu from tensorflow.

Comment: But how can i make sure that tensorflow uses my gpu? And do you mean that if i import tensorflow in my script is automatically uses my gpu?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38559755/how-to-get-current-available-gpus-in-tensorflow To see which GPU's tf knows, unless defined explicitly, it will use GPU (if possible).

Comment: my gpu doesn't appear when i execute `device_lib.list_local_devices()` i it possible it doesn't find my gpu because i'm in an virtual environment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To ensure that the tensorflow package is using your GPU, do this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

sess = tf.Session()
```

See the output on the console, if it shows your GPU information on creation of the session as shown below.

Notice "GeForce 940MX" in the information. Also note that Tensorflow will use a Nvidia GPU **only** if the compute capability score is above 3.5 . More about that [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu).

[image: here]

If it's not using the GPU, then it won't output GPU information, it'll just show something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: I have the second output, can that be because i'm running tf in a virtual environment?

Comment: no, it means you're using the GPU version instead. I'd suggest uninstalling tensorflow by doing `pip uninstall tensorflow` and trying again.

Comment: wait... which one must i delete and install again? i'll just delete them both and install the normal tensorflow again.

Comment: Do this: `pip uninstall tensorflow`, I think you have both CPU and GPU versions installed and thus the confusion.  If you do `pip uninstall tensorflow-gpu` it uninstalls tensorflow GPU. If you do `pip uninstall tensorflow` it uninstalls tensorflow CPU.

Comment: yeah now i've tried with the normal one and nothing works, i'm now trying with the gpu one

Comment: ok it seems that the gpu one doenst work if you don't have the normal one installed, now i've installed them both and still get the second output when i execute 
`sess = tf.Session()`

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Could you try this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50538927/6400614

Answer (score 4):

The package on pypi is called tensorflow-gpu but you just import it with "tensorflow"

```
 import tensorflow as tf
```

Comment: You could check if your GPU is being used first. If your GFX card is from NVidia, Tensorflow will use your GPU. If you have an AMD card, you will have check if your card is supported by `PlaidML`. If it is, install `PlaidML`, tell TF to use it and off you go.


Check GPU usage Windows 10: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-track-gpu-performance-data-windows-10

PlaidML: https://github.com/plaidml/plaidml

Comment: It has both GPU and CPU implementation. But the GPU devices will be given priority when the operation is assigned to a device. To find out which device is used, you can enable log device placement like this - `sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))`

Comment: my GFX is from NVidia but it doesn't use my gpu (i have a gtx1050) and whatever is stored in "sess" is `>>> sess
<tensorflow.python.client.session.Session object at 0x000001E2587F8C18>`